# Standing at elokeinu in zimmun

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, bentching, standing-sitting

Whenever I am in a situation of saying ברכת המזון with 10 people, some of the ציבור will stand for saying the word אלקנו in the זימון, others will not move at all, with lots of people somewhere in between. Is there a source for standing? If so, does the compromise bottom shuffle kind of thing accomplish anything?